# Using derived table to only return row with greater value in cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a derived table that combines two queries that that connected using UNION. There reason the table is derived is because there is a case where the same person's total shows up twice. If this is the case I want to show only the row whoes total is bigger:

[image]

Thus the derived table has the command:

```
MAX(DerivedTable.TotalHours)
```

As part of it's SELECT command. However, this is not working. How can I only show the entries for ************harplessa) whoes total is 40 hours.

```
SELECT RowType
    ,Person
    ,[Status] 
    ,OrganizationalTeam 
    ,Project
    ,Sprint
    ,Story 
    ,[Task] 
    ,MondayHours 
    ,TuesdayHours 
    ,WednesdayHours
    ,ThursdayHours
    ,FridayHours
    ,SaturdayHours
    ,SundayHours
    ,MAX(DerivedTable.TotalHours)
    FROM (
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,'' AS [Status]
        ,'' AS OrganizationalTeam
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS Sprint
        ,'' AS Story
        ,'Subtotal:' AS Task
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN2 ON (
            PDT.PK_Product = UAN2.ProductId
            AND UAN2.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND UAN2.ProductId LIKE @productId
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    --

    UNION

    --
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,'' AS [Status]
        ,'' AS OrganizationalTeam
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS Sprint
        ,'' AS Story
        ,'Subtotal:' AS Task
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN1 ON (
            USR.PK_User = UAN1.UserId
            AND UAN1.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND UAN1.OrganizationalTeamId LIKE @teamId
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    ) AS DerivedTable
        GROUP BY 
        DerivedTable.RowType, 
        DerivedTable.Person,
        DerivedTable.[Status],
        DerivedTable.OrganizationalTeam,
        DerivedTable.Project,
        DerivedTable.Sprint,
        DerivedTable.Story,
        DerivedTable.[Task],
        DerivedTable.MondayHours,
        DerivedTable.TuesdayHours,
        DerivedTable.WednesdayHours,
        DerivedTable.ThursdayHours,
        DerivedTable.FridayHours,
        DerivedTable.SaturdayHours,
        DerivedTable.SundayHours,
        DerivedTable.TotalHours
```

Comment: don't group by DerivedTable.TotalHours

Comment: I removed it, got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the results of a `group by` clause, use `having`

```
group by ...
having Max(derivedtable.totalhours)> 40
```

If you want to show only the highest row for each person

```
Select * 
from 
     (Select *, row_number() over (partition by person order by TotalHours desc) rn 
      from derivedtable
     ) v
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I see what you mean. This is useful but it's not that I want the hours to be over than 40. I want the row with the higher total to show while the other doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to implement this but I dont exactly see where. Does the query wrap around the derivedTable view?